# Android, Robotium - How to work with localized builds?

Tags: robotium

I'm using Robotium for some test automation for an Android application. It's great, but the maintenance is huge.

My application is localized into 20 languages, I'm compiling my application string resources into my test APK (that contains the logic for running my automated tests) and using the strings to find menu items etc. to click at run time. This is in line with an example I found on the Robotium project page on Google Code.

For example,

```
solo.clickOnText(res.getString(R.string.settings_menu));
```

The problem I'm having is that the strings may change daily in early builds of my product.

Is there any way I can use the string ID's as opposed to the actual strings in order to click on items? These would be unique across all languages, and I wouldn't have the high maintenance costs I currently have.

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the resource ids of the views that you want to interact with. An example is:

```
Button button = (Button) solo.getView(R.id.x);
solo.clickOnView(button);
```

Comment: Thanks Renas - what about text links? Does the above pnly work for buttons? I've got lots of text links in my app.

Comment: You do the same but replace Button with TextView instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use

```
String myLocalizedString = getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.settings_menu);
solo.clickOnText(myLocalizedString);
```

No matter what you change your language to it should come up with the correct string. I am assuming you are using [resource qualifiers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources).

```
res
  values
    strings.xml
  values-fr
    strings.xml
```

Comment: This is the approach I'm currently using. My question is if there is an alternative. In R.java when I compile my app, unique string IDs seem to be generated, if I could use these as opposed to the actual string values, I wouldn't have to worry about having the correct string resources (which change daily in early builds)

Comment: `getActivity().getString()` is a bit shorter

Answer (score 0):

Use resource id from the test tested project(if you are testing APK only, import the R.java to your testing project).

Then use scripts like below:

```
View view = solo.getCurrentActivity().findViewById(R.id.resourceId);
solo.clickOnView(view);
```